# Is a question about CSS framework integration too broad so SO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, needs-more-focus

So I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738620/better-method-to-install-a-css-framework#. A fairly big part of me wants to flag this as too broad, because I can actually make a fairly good case for both methods outlined in the question and even think of a specific third one for .NET, but it is a question that beginners might what to know.

But I guess the thing that bugs me the most is the way the question is formed. I simply can't shake the feeling that this is a question from a test or a homework assignment or something like that and that just rubs me the wrong way.

If this would be a clearly bad question I would simply down vote this and move own, but I'm really puzzled by this one and simply can't decide what to do with it. Leave it alone, down vote it and leave a "fairly mean" (at least I believe it will come out that way) comment explaining the down vote or even flag it as off topic?

Comment: the core question is "What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method?"  That probably means that it is too broad

Comment: It's less about what the question is about, and more about what the question is asking for. Typically if someone asks "what is best" it's too opinionated, and "what are the pros/cons" is *almost* always too broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that a question is something a lot of people would want to know doesn't make a question any less broad, or in any way more appropriate if it were to meet any other close criteria.  If it is in fact too broad then it should be closed as such.

Whether a question is related to a homework (or another type of) assignment has no bearing on the question quality or whether or not it should be closed.  Many of these types of questions happen to have other problems, but you should close the question because of those other problems that they have (being too broad, or unclear, or whatever) rather than because you know (or think) that it is a homework assignment.

It certainly looks too broad to me, and I would have voted to close it as such if it were still open.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it is a homework question really does not matter. The thing was rightfully closed as opinion-based. When someone just asks what is "better", the answers are always going to be opinion-based.

Better how? Easier? Faster? Cleaner? More robust? .... Even if "better" is clarified somehow, the answer to the specific kind of better in many cases depends on the specifics of the problem and if the specifics are not defined then what you get are opinions.